# Alerting on threshold crossing?

Tags: security, monitoring, logging, alerts, logstash

We are using `logstash + elasticsearch + Kibana` to parse, store and view our logs respectively.

Now, we want a notification/alert when a **threshold** for a particular log or threshold for a particular field (after parsing) is crossed. Eg: On a server number of logins per day is max 5. Now we want a notification if this threshold is crossed.

Can this be done via the tools we are using presently?? 
If not, can anyone suggest any open-source tools to achieve this and can be confiugerd with the present setup??

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While not directly related to logstash OSSEC may be able to help out more in the alerting category.

I'm sure you could define thresholds within the system to alert.

http://www.ossec.net/files/auscert-2007-dcid.pdf

For general alerting and monitoring a combination of factors is good. You could even expose a counter to nagios to do alerting for you if you created the right sort of URL.